# Nitration of haloarene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds

**Question**: Convert benzene to 4-bromonitrobenzene.

**My attempt:**

[image]

**Answer given:**

[image]

Is my solution correct? Can aryl halodes react directly with $\ce{AgNO2}$ to form aryl nitrate?

Comment: AgNO2 may react with the two bromine atoms.

Comment: Or, in this case, with neither - this is a method for aliphatic nitro compounds not aromatic.

Comment: (1) The bromine workup in your answer can be quite messy. If you increase the concentration of bromine, it can lead multiple isomer(both o- and p-isomer). It can also lead to formation of the tribromo- compound. (2) Why do you think AgNO2 will react with one bromine atom? (3) AgNO2 does react more with alkyl halides than aromatic halides